# Best data structures for 3D array in Python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, dictionary, hashtable

I am developing a moving average filter for position "tracks" in [Touch Designer](http://www.derivative.ca/), which implements a Python runtime.  I'm new to Python and I'm unclear on the best data structures to use.  The pcode is roughly:

1. Receive a new list of tracks formatted as:

       
   id, posX, posY
       2001, 0.54, 0.21
       2002, 0.43, 0.23
       ...

   Add incoming X and Y values to an existing data structure keyed on "id," if that id is already present

   Create new entries for new ids

   Remove any id entries that are not present in the incoming data

   Return a moving average of X and Y values per id

Question: Would it be a good idea to do this as a hashtable where the key is id, and the values are a list of lists? eg:

`ids = {2001: posVals, 2002: posVals2}`

where `posVals` is a list of [x,y] pairs?

I think this is like a 3D array, but where I want to use id as a key for lots of operations.

Thanks

Comment: What you're using is a dictionary (`dict` in python). Your implementation seems logical, and I think it will work. The only problem I foresee you having is that you will need to do a linear pass every time you get a new list of tracks, to check which of those tracks you should delete. Realistically though, I don't see you being able to do too much better than O(n), so that shouldn't be too much of an issue

Comment: What's the range of ID values? How densely packed do you expect it to be? How many x,y pairs do you expect for each one?

Comment: Thanks.  Range of ID = 0-max int.  Perhaps max 20 ids in the array at one time, and up to 60 x,y pairs per ID.  So 20 ids * 60 = 1200 pairs.  Something like that.

Comment: OK, 1200 pairs sounds reasonable for a dict of lists of pairs. If you build it and it turns out to be too slow, revisit the question; otherwise, I think your instincts were good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if the IDs are all relatively small positive integers, and the array is almost completely dense (that is, almost all IDs will exist), a dict is just adding extra overhead. On the other hand, if there are large numbers, or large gaps, or keys of different types, using a dict as a "sparse array" makes perfect sense.

Meanwhile, for the other two dimensions… how many IDs are you going to have, and how many pairs for each? If we're talking a handful of pairs per ID and a few thousands total pairs across all IDs, a list of pairs per ID is perfectly fine (although I'd probably represent each pair as a tuple rather than a list), and anything else would be adding unnecessary complexity. But if there are going to be a lot of pairs per ID, or a lot total, you may run into problems with storage, or performance.

If you can use the third-party library `numpy`, it can store a 2D array of numbers in much less memory than a list of pairs of numbers, and it can perform calculations like moving averages with much briefer/more readable code, and with much less CPU time. In fact, it can even store a sparse 3D array for you.

If you can only use the standard library, the `array` module can get you most of the same memory benefits, but without the simplicity benefits (in fact, your code becomes slightly *more* complex, as you have to represent the 2D array as a 1D array, old-school-C-style—although you can wrap that up pretty easily), or the time performance benefits, and it can't help with the sparseness.

Comment: Thanks for this info, super helpful.  The ids will be small in number at any given time, perhaps topping out at 15-20 tracks.  The ids will also almost certainly be non-sequential as some tracks leave earlier than others.  The track id ints will be large (eg: 240516) as the tracker never recycles id values.

Comment: @damon_s: What seems to be missing there is how many x,y values there will be for each of the 15-20 tracks. If we're talking a few dozen, then your design is more than sufficient, and has the huge advantage of not requiring anything beyond what's built in to Python and understandable to novices. You might want to look at using numpy or a stats-collection module anyway, just to make the moving average calculation a one-liner, but otherwise there's no reason to go more complex than a dict of lists of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how I would do it.  It's very intuitive this way, assuming you're always looking things up by their id and don't need to sort in some other way.

Also, the terminology in Python is `dict` (as in dictionary), rather than hashtable.